# Can't resolve all parameters for HttpParams: (?)

Tags: angular

So when I do this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { EnvironmentConfig } from '../../../common/shared/environment-config/environment-config.service';

@Injectable()
export class AccessRequestService {
  private url: string;

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private config: EnvironmentConfig
  ) {
    this.url = this.config['api'];
  }

  getRequests(start: string, end: string): Observable<any> {
    const params = new HttpParams();
    params.set('start', start);
    params.set('end', end);

    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/objects`, { params })
      .timeout(12000)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json().objects);
  }
}
```

I get an error

```
main.ssi.ts:10 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HttpParams: (?).
    at syntaxError (http://ssi.local:4200/vendor.bundle.js:27181:34)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http://ssi.local:4200/vendor.bundle.js:41256:35)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (http://ssi.local:4200/vendor.bundle.js:41124:26)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (http://ssi.local:4200/vendor.bundle.js:41110:21)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (http://ssi.local:4200/vendor.bundle.js:41401:40)
    at http://ssi.local:4200/vendor.bundle.js:41330:49
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at
```

and I already provided HttpParams in the module

Comment: Did you inject HttpParams in constructor?

Comment: @yurzui no, should I ? I import it though

Comment: Can you add more code? DId you add it to providers somewhere?

Comment: @yurzui I edded the whole class

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't include it in constructor?

Comment: @yurzui yes I'm sure

Comment: @yurzui But I think the problem is because I provide it in the module

Comment: I think you need to delete it immediately!)

Comment: @yurzui thanks, that was the problem, I shouldn't have provided it in the module

Answer (score 0):

HI can you try this post

[Http params in Angular 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45374425/7261317)

if you want know more

refer the docs [http headers](https://angular.io/guide/http#headers)